# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\images\\\\imagetest.png'

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am a begginer programer in python and when i run this code

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(r'C:\\images\\imagetest.png')
width, height = im.size
print(width, height)
im.show()
```

I get this error:

```
    im = Image.open(r'C:\\images\\imagetest.png')
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\images\\\\imagetest.png'
```

PS C:\Users\danie\vscode projects>

Comment: You can use forward slashes (on Windows as well): `im = Image.open('C:/images/imagetest.png')`

Answer (score 3):

r strings don't need their backslashes escaped

Remove the r before the string declaration or remove the double backslashes

Comment: when i remove the double backslashes i get the same error and when i removed the r i get this in  "problems": Anomalous backslash in string: '\i'. String constant might be missing an r prefix. and also get the same error of before in the terminal/

Comment: @DanielKrieze, Edward is correct. It should work with this path: `r'C:\images\imagetest.png'`. That is if the file actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

The path of the image is not correct. You have to write it like that:

im = Image.open(r'C:\images\imagetest.png')

Comment: Are you sure that the image is in the current path? If there is not any same file named file in the path the program gives you the same error. Can you check it

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, the path you gave is incorrect.
this

```
im = Image.open(r'C:\\images\\imagetest.png')
```

have issues such as double "\" which is not the proper format.
Sometimes you also have the give it the full path:
Example of a path:

```
C:\Users\Hamza\Downloads\me.jpg
```

If you're not sure about the path
copy it from here
[example path for an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncc9X.png)